# Set Bootstrap modal title as an image using jQuery & Razor

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to set a modal's title with jQuery. I want the title to be: text + tiny profile picture + text.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$(".ModalTitle").text('textblabla' + @Html.Raw("<img src=\"image.png\" />") + textblabla);
```

This doesn't give me any errors, but when I start the website and check the console it says:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

How can this be solved?

**Edit:**  I don't think I'm escaping the last " after the image url..

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well?

Comment: why do you need that to be in html.raw?  Also you should use `.html` instead of `.text` and the razor should be part of the quoted text: `.html('textblabla<img src="image.png" />textblabla')`.  The way you are doing it at the moment it will be trying to add the image tag but as the quotes aren't around it it will be treating it as a variable which is why you have the unexpected token

Comment: Thanks!

$(".ModalTitle").html('<img src="image.png" />');

Works.

Comment: @Pete You should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Pete's comment may provide the simplest answer. If your content is more complex it may keep things more clear to separate the 3 operations:

```
$('.ModalTitle')
  .html('<img src="image.png" />')
  .prepend('Text before the image. ')
  .append(' Text after the image.');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wsu1x6ky/)**

Using single quotes for JavaScript and double for HTML prevents the need for backslash escapes.